# Unable to attach Visual Studio 2013 debugger with x64 process

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I am trying to attach the running w3wp x64 process (application in my local machine), Visual Studio 2013 throws error

> Unable to attach to the process. The Remote Debugger was unable to
>   locate a resource dll (vsdebugeng.impl.resources.dll). Please ensure
>   that the complete remote debugger folder was copied or installed on
>   the target computer.

[Screenshot Ref:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhOOz.png)

I am struggling with this problem from 24-Sep-2018.

Comment: This file normally lives in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\xxxx where xxxx is the language identifier.  1033 for US English for example.  SO users ought to complete their profile so we can tell where they live.  Figure out where you live, check if the file is still there.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant
Yes, the file "vsdebugeng.impl.resources.dll" was there. But unable to attach the debugger. While attaching Visual Studio shows message "Unable to attach to the process. The Remote Debugger was unable to locate a resource dll (vsdebugeng.impl.resources.dll). Please ensure that the complete remote debugger folder was copied or installed on the target computer."

Comment: The remote debugger is always used for a 64-bit app, VS is a 32-bit process.  So the error message is a bit misleading, nothing actually needs to be copied.  You still have not updated your profile, the language ID matters.  Good luck with it.

Comment: But I am facing this issue only for past 4+ days. Prior to that I can able to attach the debugger from Visual Studio for the localhost URL without any problem. Anyway, if I found solution I will come up with it