# The Remote Debugger was unable to locate a resource dll (vsdebugeng.impl.resources.dll) - VS 2017 CE 15.8.7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

---

### Scenario

I'm trying to run the default application from Visual Studio 2017 CE.
I just create a sample .Net core web application and built it successfully.
Once I start running my application, its end-up with a error prompt contains below error message.

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio Error Message

Unable to attach. The Remote Debugger was unable to locate a resource dll (vsdebugeng.impl.resources.dll).
Please ensure that the complete remote debugger folder was copied or installed on the target computer.

---

### Other Information

Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition - Version 15.8.7

- OS Name: Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro OS
- Version: 6.3.9600 N/A Build 9600
- OS Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
- OS Configuration: Member Workstation OS Build
- Type: Multiprocessor Free

---

### Error Message if run as Administrator

Unable to attach. The Remote Debugger was unable to locate a resource dll (vsdebugeng.impl.resources.dll).
Please ensure that the complete remote debugger folder was copied or installed on the target computer.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error message this week, when the same copy of the remote debugger & all of its files was running fine last week.  The issue was that I forgot to run the remote debugger as an administrator.  When I re-launched the debugger as administrator, the issue went away.

This was with VS 2017 15.9.16, and I saw the error message when attempting to deploy my c++ project to the remote target machine.  This post is the only relevant google result for this error message, so hopefully my answer will help someone else running into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons for this Issue. This happens not just 2017. But also it exists in 2015 CE. Please see this thread as well [Unable to attach Visual Studio 2013 debugger with x64 process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511423/unable-to-attach-visual-studio-2013-debugger-with-x64-process/52622441#52622441)

Is this happens only for Web Application or it also exists while debugging other Projects (Azure Functions)

For Web Application, try enabling the 32 Bit in the IIS and then try attaching to the Process.

Comment: Thanks Nirmal for your suggestion. Already I applied above mentioned fixes, but no luck. 

if i change the bit to x86 mode, getting the same error.